# How do I filter test resources in maven?

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have the following `pom.xml`. When I run `mvn clean resources:testResources`, my test resources aren't being [filtered](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) (replacing placeholders in resources before they are put, in their modified form, into the output folder). Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This may be evident to op but let's state what "filtering" is: it's about replacing placeholders in resources before they are put (in their modified form) into the output folder: [Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The `resources` and `resource` elements are for the `resources:resources` goal. `resources:testResources` uses `testResources` and `testResource` elements.

The correct `pom.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>foo</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @Stephan seems quite a good idea to separate resources and test resources no ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue You're right. However the way OP tried in his question is more obvious.

Comment: Is it possible to change ${var} to @var@ matchers?