# Maven TestNG project, pass command line arguments to testng.xml file

Tags: maven, command-line, testng, pom.xml

I have a Maven TestNG project, and am trying pass couple of command line arguments into the testng.xml file.

The testng.xml file looks like below:

```
<suite name="Test Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="100" >
  <test name="VIP Tests">
    <parameter name="browser" value="${browser}" />
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="${test.scope}" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <packages>
        <package name="com.tests.*" />
    </packages>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

The pom.xml file looks like below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Test_Project</groupId>
<artifactId>TP_X</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                   <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Now, every time I attempt to execute the Maven test command

```
mvn clean test -U -Dtest.scope=smoke -Dbrowser=chrome
```

I get the following error in the command line:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project VIP_QE: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
[ERROR] Illegal repetition near index 0
[ERROR] ${test.scope}
```

Can someone please help? I have been stuck with this problem for about a week.

Comment: The Maven command that I am using is "mvn clean test -U -Dtest.scope=smoke -Dbrowser=chrome". Apologies for missing out the browser parameter.

Comment: @nullpointer Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestNG and surefire are not supporting the `${var}` notation.

But you can use [the filtering feature of Maven](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html). Then you'll have to choose the modified resource:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Test_Project</groupId>
<artifactId>TP_X</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <sourceDirectory>${src.dir}</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                   <suiteXmlFile>target/test-classes/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Note the difference between `testResources` and `resources`: [How do I filter test resources in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176399/how-do-i-filter-test-resources-in-maven)