# How do I pass a parameter from jenkins to TestNg

Tags: jenkins, testng

How can I pass a parameter from Jenkins to TestNG. I want to pass the application URL as a parameter to my testNg file. The reason I want to do this is to run tests simultaneously on multiple test environments.

At the moment the url is in the testNg xml file

Here is a snapshot of my POM

```html
<plugins>
<!-- surefire plugin -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.19.1</version>
<configuration>
<suiteXmlFiles>

src/test/resources/testng.xml

</suiteXmlFiles>
<filtering>true</filtering>

</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an environment variable for that purpose.

By having a look at the Jenkins documentation for [Parametrized Build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), one can set parameters on builds. These are then made available as environment variables during the build.

In case your are using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), in order to have TestNG use the environment variable, you can apply [filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to the XML file. Filtering will replace any occurrence of, for example, `${URL}`, with the value of the `URL` environment variable.

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24176400/558825) to understand how to do it.